# Prevent jssor slider background pattern to scale

Tags: background-image, jssor

Is it possible to put a background-image pattern in a jssor slider and avoid to scale when resizing the screen?

This is the original background pattern

[image: background 1]

This is what happen when reducing the browser window

[image: background 2]

```
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:50px;left:0px;width:3000px;height:1500px;overflow:hidden; background-image: url(img/pattern.jpg); background-repeat:repeat;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jssor slider will always scale to fit the parent container.

You can create a div wit background image, and place jssor slider in the div.